# sp_refreshview throws unexpected error

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, view

I am currently writing a TSQL script where part of the script refreshes all of the views within the database. After finding [this](http://yellowduckguy.wordpress.com/2008/08/10/refresh-all-views-in-database-with-t-sql/) example online I am iterating through the collection but getting a strange issue when refreshing one of the views (not the first).

On running the below query I get a result back from the sysobjects table

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'V' AND name = 'vwEnginesFinishBuiltToday'
```

[image]

Then running the refresh I get an exception back

```
exec sp_refreshview N'dbo.vwEnginesFinishBuiltToday'
```

[image]

Now the strange thing is the error is telling me a view with a different name can not be found. Its true that it does not exist in the database so thinking that `dbo.vwEnginesFinishBuiltToday` was using another view internally I looked at the TSQL of the view.

```
SELECT     COUNT(dbo.tblBatches.IdBatch) AS TotalEnginesFinishedToday
FROM         dbo.tblBatches INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tblEngines ON dbo.tblBatches.IdBatch = dbo.tblEngines.idBatch
WHERE     (YEAR(dbo.tblEngines.DateFinished) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AND (MONTH(dbo.tblEngines.DateFinished) = MONTH(GETDATE())) AND (DAY(dbo.tblEngines.DateFinished) 
                      = DAY(GETDATE()))
```

Mmmmm, no mention of the `dbo.vwEnginesFinishedToday` view there. No I'm struggling to find the issue.

Is there a problem with the `sp_refreshsqlmodule_internal` method in SQL Server or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you previously changed the name of the view with [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx)?

Comment: Afraid its not my database. I have no knowledge of what the previous developer changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've renamed the view at some point in the past, either using [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) or the SSMS Object Explorer. When you try to refresh the view, `sp_refreshview` is trying to alter the view using the original view name, which no longer exists.

Try using the `Script View as -> ALTER To -> New Query Editor Window` option to generate the `ALTER VIEW` script, execute the script, and then try `sp_refreshview` again.

Comment: Looks like that was the problem. I generated and ran the Alter View script and the sp_refreshview command now works. Very strange issue. Thanks for your help